# Get events for browser action

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to event when

- Browser **reload icon** pressed
- Browser **Back** and **Forward** icon Press
- Press **Reload** menu item from browser context menu
- Press **Reload** from View Menu from any browser
- Page getting refresh from **URL Textbox**

How can I do that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: These will all trigger the `beforeunload` and `unload` events.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to know which kind of action triggered it. All you can tell is that the page is unloading for some reason. Why do you need to know which icon is pressed?

Comment: @Barmar. I want to prevent refresh page. For this I develop a code in javascript on keypress, I disable F5, Ctrl + F5, Ctrl + R. But sir above given situation how can I prevent refresh?

Comment: You can't prevent it. The best you can do is display a prompt asking if the user really wants to reload the page, by using the `beforeunload` event.

Comment: @Barmar using code, API, logic, etc... there is not any way to prevent? Because as per client requirement I must not show any prompt to user

Comment: No, it's a security feature. Adware used to prevent users from navigating away from the page, so browsers don't allow this any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reload and refresh use:

1. window.onbeforeunload (calls on Browser/tab Close & Page Load)
2. window.onload (calls on Page Load)
3. window.onunload (unloading its content and resources)

But a better way to know that the page is actually reloaded is to use the HTML 5 navigation time API.

```
// check for navigation time API support
if (window.performance) {
   console.log("window.performance work's fine on this browser");
}

if (performance.navigation.type == 1) {
  console.log( "This page is reloaded" );
} else {
  console.log( "This page is not reloaded");
}
```

For back and forward button go with HTML5 [demo](http://html5demos.com/history)

```
window.addEventListener("popstate", function(e) {
    // if a back or forward button is clicked
    // do whatever
});
```

Comment: thank you sir. When I use onload event also trigger when page load and page refresh. Sir I want only page refresh event.

Comment: @RkinfotechPhp I am glad it solved you problem. Happy coding! :)